# How do I run long running queries when there are constant writes in Sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

I have an sqlite3 database that has one process inserting a single row every second or so. Is it possible to execute a long running query on this database in another process? When I try I'm often getting "database locked" errors. Do both the reader and the writer require exclusive access to the database? Will a very long read-only query cause the writes to fail?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the WAL journal mode.